# Use Eshell with Tramp, from a Windows computer to a Linux server

Tags: microsoft-windows, tramp, eshell

I use a Windows computer to control servers through Tramp (with plink). 
Here's my setup:

```lisp
(setq explicit-shell-file-name "/bin/bash")
(setq default-directory "/plink:user@server:~")
```

Now when I run M-x shell it runs perfectly. All commands (w, ls...) work on the server.

M-x eshell does get me a prompt on the distant server. However, here's what I get with *w*:

```
/plink:user@server:/home/user $ w
w: command not found
```

The *ls* command on the current directory works. However, I cannot change directory :

```
/plink:user@server:/home/user $ cd Videos
No such directory found via CDPATH environment variable
```

Except if I use this [small hack](https://www.reddit.com/r/emacs/comments/5spjv5/tramp_eshell_doesnt_know_where_i_am/) found on Reddit :

```
/plink:user@server:/home/user $ cd $PWD/Videos/
/plink:user@server:/home/user:/home/user/Videos $
```

So, what elements of configuration am I missing to have a working eshell on my distant server?

Comment: I'm not quite sure, but I believe there were related bugs in Emacs, which are fixed. If you have a chance to test with a snapshot version of Emacs 27.1, this might be fixed. If not, pls send a bug report.